# Contact Page not working (php)

Tags: php, html, contacts, modx, formit

So I have made a contact page in modx with this code

```
<!-- Start Contact Form -->


<div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <form action="mail.php" class="contactForm" name="cform" method="post">
    <div class="row">
```

I have also uploaded the `mail.php` file into assets but it still doesn't seem to work. So far I tried `path/to/assets/mail.php` which didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where's the php file?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Please dump `mail.php` and any error you get.

Comment: Are you sure the mail.php is on the same request level? This form will submit its contents to `where you are now/mail.php`

Comment: when you said that you tried "path/to/assets/mail.php" did you try physical path on drive or web path to that file? The form must use web path. Best way to work this out is to put some echo on top of your mail.php and see if you get to it when pressing the submit button. If not there can be 3 reasons: 1) your path in action is not correct. 2) you submit button is not submitting the form (faults in html layout) 3) some javascript is blocking the default action of submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Change your form action as following path look like **..assets/example.php**

```
 <div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <form action="..yourpath/mail.php" class="contactForm" name="cform" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
```

Comment: php file contain in another folder so change that action as path

Comment: tnx for your opinion. i change my answer. @Epodax

Answer (score 1):

This isnt "modx-way". Here simple example https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.tutorials-and-examples/formit.examples.simple-contact-page how it should be.